# How to generate a dictionary for the class (vector<vector<short> >)

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, makefile, root-framework

I have a simple code that I wrote in C++ and compile it using make. 
I don't get error when I compile. But when I run it, I get an error caused by `std::vector< std::vector<short> >`, see below the error:

> Error in `<TTree::SetBranchAddress>`: Unable to determine the type given for the address for "apv_q". The class expected (`vector<vector<short> >`) refers to an stl collection and do not have a compiled CollectionProxy.  Please generate the dictionary for this class (`vector<vector<short> >`)

`TTree::SetBranchAddress` is a method from CERN-ROOT framework

apv_q is defined as `std::vector< std::vector<short> > *apv_q;`

I am not familiar with generating dictionaries, so I searched online and found the suggestion to add the lines below in the header file

```
 #ifdef __MAKECINT__
 #pragma link C++ class vector<short> +;
 #pragma link C++ class vector<vector<short> >+;
 #endif
```

But it doesn't work!

**So I need your help to fix this problem, please help!**

Thanks a lot in advance!

Cheers,

Eda

If relevant, below is my MakeFile:

```
      CONFIG=root-config
      CXXFLAGS=$(shell $(CONFIG) --cflags)
      LIBS=$(shell $(CONFIG) --glibs)
      LDFLAGS=$(shell $(CONFIG) --ldflags)
      CXX=g++
      ADDCXXFLAGS=-ggdb -O0 -std=c++0x

      HDRS= ./Settings.h ./HitMaker.h

      HITMAKEROBJS=   HitMaker.o

      all: hitmaker

      hitmaker: $(HITMAKEROBJS)
              $(CXX) -o $@ $(CXXFLAGS) $(ADDCXXFLAGS) $(HITMAKEROBJS) $(LDFLAGS) $(LIBS)

      %.o: %.cc $(HDRS)
              $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(ADDCXXFLAGS) -c $<
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to run [`root-cint`](https://root.cern.ch/root/RootCintMan.html) and give it a list of your header files, including the `LinkDef.h` which contains the lines

```
#pragma link C++ class vector<short> +;
#pragma link C++ class vector<vector<short> >+;
```

This tool then creates a source file which you can compile and link to your project.

You may want to include this task in your Makefile, there are some macros available for CMake if you want to use that (search for `FindRoot.cmake`, this includes the macro `ROOT_GENERATE_DICTIONARY`).

EDIT: It works for me, when I run

```
rootcint -f bla.cc -c HitMaker.h LinkDef.h
```

and add in the Makefile

```
HITMAKEROBJS=HitMaker.o bla.o
```

I created a root file with

```
TFile file("test.root", "RECREATE");
TTree tree("tree", "treetitle");
std::vector<std::vector<short>> test;
std::vector<short> test2;
test2.push_back(1);
test.push_back(test2);
tree.Branch("test", &test);
tree.Fill();
tree.Write();
```

and read it back with

```
TFile file("test.root");
TTree* t= NULL;
file.GetObject("tree", t);
std::vector<std::vector<short>>* test = NULL;
t->SetBranchAddress("test", &test);
t->GetEvent(0);
std::cout << test->front().front() << std::endl;
```

The value `1` is written to stdout.

Comment: BTW, ROOT has its own [container classes](https://root.cern.ch/doc/master/classTArrayS.html), so it may be an alternative to use those instead of `std::vector`

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I have more questions. Well, I checked rootcint and did `rootcint -f bla.cc -c HitMaker.h LinkDef.h`. It created bla.cc and bla.h as expected. I am confused with the compiling, I changed my make file to have 

`HDRS= $(HDIR)/Settings.h $(HDIR)/HitMaker.h $(HDIR)/bla.h`

`HITMAKEROBJS=   HitMaker.o`
but it gives the same error. 
If I add bla.o to HITMAKEROBJS then it complains about multiple definition of variables. 
What should I do?

Comment: Which version of root are you using? I have 5.34 on Debian 8.

Comment: I have 5.34 too, on SL6

Comment: What's the exact error when you add `bla.o` to `HITMAKEROBJS`?

Comment: bla.o: In function `DictInit':
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/../../../../include/c++/4.4.7/new:101: multiple definition of `apv_evt'
HitMaker.o:/afs/desy.de/user/y/yeda/nfs_yeda/MainzAnalysis/old/HitMaker.cc:30: first defined here
   (and same for other variables)

Comment: What is `apv_evt`? Is it a class or an instance variable?

Comment: it is an unsigned int, just the event number in the tree

Comment: Can you show the definition? Or better, post the complete header file, or put it somewhere, e.g. [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/).

Comment: The [header file](http://pastebin.com/fPPzefxh) , [Makefile](http://pastebin.com/cHBNuq5V) and also if relevant [source file](http://pastebin.com/0eb9FGvy)

Comment: OK, so those are global variables, declared in the header file. As the header file is supposed to be included in multiple places, this creates problems, as you then also have multiple instances of these variables. The solution is to use the `extern` keyword to declare those, and only define them once in a .cc file. Or, even better: Try to not use global variables. Put them in your class, and if they really have to be global, make them static.

Comment: In your case, you could simply move the global variables from the .h to the .cc file

Comment: Perfect! Worked! Thank you very very much! You are the best, you are the greatest :)

Comment: If my answer was helpful, you could upvote or even accept it

Comment: Well it was definitely helpful, I can't upvote since I don't have enough reputation but I did accept it. Thanks a lot!